# Positioning an SVG image element in an SVG html item

Tags: javascript, image, svg

I'm about to write some JavaScript that wraps around SVG for convenience. This code can take an SVG section of a HTML page and insert SVG items dynamically. This works quite well for rectangles and circles and these kind of shapes, but it does not work for images: Whenever I create an image item the Y position of the image is way off. X is fine: An X-value of zero renders the image left aligned with the SVG canvas. But it is quite strange: I require a negative Y-value for the image to align to the top of the SVG.canvas. In contrast to primitive shapes if I specify zero for Y for images these images get centered vertically within my SVG canvas. Why is that the case? What am I missing?

The essential aspects of my code:

```
function __makeSVG(tag, attrs)
{
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}
```

And:

```
function createImageXY(x, y, url) {
    var style = {};
    style["x"] = x;
    style["y"] = y;
    style["width"] = "100%";
    style["height"] = "100%";
    style["visibility"] = "visible";
    var svgItem = __makeSVG('image', style);
    svgItem.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);
    main.appendChild(svgItem);
}
```

And the SVG canvas in HTML is created like this:

```
<svg id="viewport" style="stroke-width: 0px; background-color: black; width:1200px; height:800px"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
</svg>
```

More strangely: If I scale the image the vertical position will be scaled as well.

I would like to have absolute positioning like I have for rectangles and circles and these things. A position of (100, 100) should position the image to exact (100, 100) and not somewhere else. What am I missing? How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I correct in guessing that the image you are using is wider than it is high?  Like this example?

```js
var main = document.getElementById("viewport");


function __makeSVG(tag, attrs)
{
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}

function createImageXY(x, y, url) {
    var style = {};
    style["x"] = x;
    style["y"] = y;
    style["width"] = "100%";
    style["height"] = "100%";
    style["visibility"] = "visible";
    var svgItem = __makeSVG('image', style);
    svgItem.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);
    main.appendChild(svgItem);
}

createImageXY(0, 0, "https://placekitten.com/400/200");
```

```html
<svg id="viewport" style="stroke-width: 0px; background-color: black; width:1200px; height:800px"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

When you specify `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` for an SVG image element, you are not saying "draw the image at the image's natural width and height". Nor are you saying "draw it at the same width and height as the `<svg>`".

What you are saying is "draw the image at its normal aspect ratio, but scaled up to fit inside a box that is the same width and height as the `<svg>`".

So in my example above, the 400x200 image is being scaled up to neatly fit inside the 1200x800 `<svg>`.  When you do that, the image is actually drawn at 1200x600. That's the largest size it can be and still fit inside the SVG.

Additionally, by default, the image gets centred inside that "viewport". Which means there is 200 pixels (800  - 600 ) of blank space that gets distributed above and below the scaled image.

**Solution 1: stretch the image**

If you want the image to be exactly the same width and height of the SVG. Then you can set `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, which will cause it to be stretched vertically and horizontally to the same size as the SVG.

```js
var main = document.getElementById("viewport");


function __makeSVG(tag, attrs)
{
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}

function createImageXY(x, y, url) {
    var style = {};
    style["x"] = x;
    style["y"] = y;
    style["width"] = "100%";
    style["height"] = "100%";
    style["visibility"] = "visible";
    style["preserveAspectRatio"] = "none";
    var svgItem = __makeSVG('image', style);
    svgItem.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);
    main.appendChild(svgItem);
}

createImageXY(100, 100, "https://placekitten.com/400/200");
```

```html
<svg id="viewport" style="stroke-width: 0px; background-color: black; width:1200px; height:800px"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

**Solution 2: position at top left of image viewport instead of centering**

You can keep the scaling that preserves the aspect ratio, but disable the centering behaviou by setting `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"`.  This value tells it to position the top left of the image at the `x`,`y`, coordinates you have specified.

```js
var main = document.getElementById("viewport");


function __makeSVG(tag, attrs)
{
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}

function createImageXY(x, y, url) {
    var style = {};
    style["x"] = x;
    style["y"] = y;
    style["width"] = "100%";
    style["height"] = "100%";
    style["visibility"] = "visible";
    style["preserveAspectRatio"] = "xMinYMin";
    var svgItem = __makeSVG('image', style);
    svgItem.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);
    main.appendChild(svgItem);
}

createImageXY(100, 100, "https://placekitten.com/400/200");
```

```html
<svg id="viewport" style="stroke-width: 0px; background-color: black; width:1200px; height:800px"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

**Solution 3: give it a real size instead of percentage size**

Specify a width and height that is appropriate, rather than using percentages.  But remember that if you specify a width and height that have a different aspect ration different from the image, you will still see the same problem.

```js
var main = document.getElementById("viewport");


function __makeSVG(tag, attrs)
{
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}

function createImageXY(x, y, url) {
    var style = {};
    style["x"] = x;
    style["y"] = y;
    style["width"] = "600";
    style["height"] = "300";
    style["visibility"] = "visible";
    var svgItem = __makeSVG('image', style);
    svgItem.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);
    main.appendChild(svgItem);
}

createImageXY(100, 100, "https://placekitten.com/400/200");
```

```html
<svg id="viewport" style="stroke-width: 0px; background-color: black; width:1200px; height:800px"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information! That explains it! Great answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: One additional question. Given an image of f.e. 234x456 pixels in size can I load this image in a way that the image object itself in SVG will (automatically) get a width of 234 and a height of 456? That's what I tried to accomplish with the "100%" - that's where I was wrong. Right now it seems to me that I always have to know the exact size of a pixel image in advance before creating an SVG image element?

Comment: No. In SVG you have to specify the size of images. The same as it is with anything else - such as rectangles.